# Hide wpf popup when click on a Winform control

Tags: wpf, popup, elementhost

I have an `ElementHost` object in a WinForm dialog. 
This elementhosts child is a `Popup`. 
I want to hide or close the `Popup` when the user clicks anywhere. I can do it when the click happened in the `Popup`. How to close it when the user clicks outside the popup, on a WinForm control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [StaysOpen=false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen.aspx)?

Comment: I don't know where to put this statement. Adding event handler which sets the StaysOpen property to false to every controls click event impossible. If Popup would be placed in a pure wpf control tree it would be easy because of the Routed event strategy. But its "grandparent" is a WinForm control.

Comment: That statement is a property of the Popup. So you set it whereever you create the popup.

Comment: Uhh, I just realized that I confused the meaning of the StaysOpen property. Thanks.